# Prove that a Boolean ring is a Bezout ring .

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that a Boolean ring is a Bezout ring .

Please help me.

Comment: You really should include your partial progress so far, even if it didn't succeed. Please try to add your efforts, or after a while people might decide to start voting to close it.

Comment: It's to your own advantage to include the context of the question, definitions that you think might apply, and where/why you're stuck on answering the question. Why is it to your advantage?: (1) Users here will be more likely to help you. (2) Users here will better know *how to help you.*

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

If you show it for ideals generated by two elements, then by induction you can do it for ideals generated by $n$ elements.

Suppose $I=\langle a,b\rangle$. Look at the ideal $\langle a+b-ab\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

We begin by proving a lemma: " Let $R$ be ring. Suppose that for all $A \subseteq R$ with $\left | A \right |=2$ then $(A)$ is principle then Then for all finite nonempty $A \subseteq R$, $(A)$ is principal.

Proof: We proceed by induction on $|A|$.

For the base case, If $|A|$ is $1$ or $2$, then $(A)$ is principal.

For the inductive step, suppose that for some $n \geq 2$, for all $A \subseteq R$ with $|A| \leq n$, $(A)$ is principal.

Let $A \subseteq R$ have cardinality $n+1$ and write $A = {x} \cup A^\prime $, where $|A^\prime| = n$.

Now $(A) = (x) + (A^\prime)$, and by the induction hypothesis, $(A^\prime) = (y)$ for some $y \in R$. Now $(A) = (x,y) = (z)$ for some $z \in R$ by hypothesis. $\square$

Now let $R$ be a Boolean ring, and let $a,b \in R$. We claim that $(a,b) = (a+ab+b)$. It is clear that $a+ab+b \in (a,b)$ since $R$ has a $1$ and is commutative.

Moreover, note that $(a+ab+b)(ab+a+1) = b$ and $(a+ab+b)(ab+b+1) = a$, so that $(a,b) \subseteq (a+ab+b)$.

Thus every subset of order $2$ generates a principal ideal in $R$, and by the lemma, every finitely generated ideal in $R$ is principal.

By the definition of Bezout domain, we imply that Boolean ring is Bezout domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot . But i don't understand why (a+ab+b)(ab+a+1)=b .

Comment: Boolean ring is  a commutative ring with the property that $a^2=a$, $\forall a\in R$